# How can i show my selected item on another page?

Tags: c#, view, asp.net-mvc-5

my project is a simple phone book ,i want to delete a contact in my(home controller) index(Left picture) and send its information to confirmation page(right picture) i want show the data of selected contact

(for example if you deleted the gjgj it's info appears  on the right side)

[image]

here is my view

```
@model IEnumerable< Project1.Models.EF_Model.Phone_book>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
@ViewBag.Massage
<div>
    <h4>Phone_book</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model =>model.Id )
        </dd>

         <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

this is the index code(Left Picture)

```
@model IEnumerable<Project1.Models.EF_Model.Phone_book>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<br /><br />
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

this is my model which i'm using in my view

```
    public partial class Phone_book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

this is my get and post code

```
   [HttpGet]
  //  [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Delete(int? _id)
    {
        Ref_ViewModel = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
        var i = Ref_ViewModel.Select(_id);
        return View(i);

    }
    #endregion

    #region [- Post -]

    [HttpPost]
    //[HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Delete(Models.EF_Model.Phone_book _Model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Ref_ViewModel = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
            Ref_ViewModel.Delete(_Model.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Massage = "Choose a Contact";
        }
        return View(_Model);
    }
    #endregion
```

how can i do that to show my selected contact in this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ActionLink as follows to redirect to another page with id say in the **Delete** view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add To Cart", "ProductDetails", "Product", new { id = item.ProductId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", alt = "@Model.ProductName" })
```

Finally grab the the id from url in the controller using the following and get the details in **Delete** view:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]);
```

Please check the link: http://kristianguevara.net/creating-your-asp-net-mvc-5-application-from-scratch-for-beginners-using-entity-framework-6-and-identity-with-crud-functionalities/

Comment: i got an error in this part [new { id = item.ProductId }]     what is item here?

Comment: I used it to iterate a loop in the view. You have a primary key in the table and use it from the model like Model.YourTableId in the view that redirects to Delete view.

Comment: wrote this ->> new {id=Model.Id } ,got this error ->> Cannot assign method group to anonymous type property

Comment: i only have 2 views first is index second would be my delete (Edited the Question though)

Comment: Share the view that you use to redirect to Delete view and the model you are using.

Comment: in my model i have another class which does my CRUD operation

Comment: OK. Everything seems fine. What error does it render when you use new { id = item.Id }?

Comment: the name item does not exist

Comment: is using IEnumrator  necessary?

Comment: I've shared a link that will help you to check what you are missing specifically check 13 and 14 (Lesson no). To me, your code looks almost perfect. No. Not necessary. Depends on your model design. Please see the edited post.

Comment: My pleasure! Good to know :)

Comment: last Question :-) is Visual studio 2015 update version 3 ready to use?because i'm using one of them